# Как сохранить изменения в vim в файле, если не хватает прав

Tags: linux, vim

Нехватает прав записать изменения в файл. Иногда прокатывает вариант `:w!`
Но на большинство файлов пишет:
`Can't open file for writing.
Press ENTER or type command to continue`

Не хватает прав.
Если открываю файл с sudo то проблем нет. Но обидно терять все сделанные изменения, если долго правил конфиг)

Comment: `sudo bash` или просто `su` (если можно) и вперед... Несколько последующих перестановок/восстановлений системы пойдут только на пользу -- приучат работать аккуратно.

Comment: тут дело не в аккуратности. Переустанавливать linux - это извращение, по моему :) Если руки кривые, то системные файлы итак лучше не трогать)

Comment: Ну, как же не в аккуратности? Работая рутом набираем `rm -rf /` -- это же просто неаккуратность. А в результате ... лучше переустановить.

Comment: поэтому под рутом работать не надо, чтобы не городить ничего. Но многие системные файлы редактируются только с правами рута. `sudo vim` и погнали.

Comment: *Но многие системные файлы редактируются только с правами рута* — вообще-то не «многие», а все до одного. по умолчанию.

Comment: Да, все так *говорят* (т.е. это *общепринято*). Уверяю, лет через пять реальной работы Ваше мнение станет отличаться от него.

Comment: интересно послушать ваше мнение на этот счет :)

Comment: Можно `sudoedit` писать - тогда ваш дефолтный editor откроется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

воспользуйтесь такой, например, командой редактора:

```
w !sudo tee %
```

---

если вы ожидаете, что файл будет доступен вам для редактирования, то, видимо, он находится в вашем домашнем каталоге. и, судя по всему, был создан вами же от имени пользователя *root*. исправить принадлежность файлов и каталогов в вашем домашнем каталоге можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

Делайте так:
в vim'е сохраните изменения в новый файл `:w new_filename.config`, затем выход `:q!`,
а потом уже от root'a или через sudo подмените файлы `mv new_filename.config needed.config`

Comment: Не очень хороший вариант, т.к. это костыли по сути, а хотелось бы универсальное решение) При вашем методе, легко могут слететь `+x` права.

Comment: В этом решении +x права действительно слетят. А что вы хотите? Не хватает прав у пользователя, так правовая политика ОС устроена. Как вариант можете нужный конфиг так переписать (для сохранения атрибутов): `cat new_config > needed_config`.

Comment: Ну или быстренько в соседней сессии владельца файла chown'ом меняйте. Только после записи обратно не забудьте сменить.